# Pygame window not displaying anything

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I am very new to Pygame and I wanted to make window that displays a purple screen with an FPS Counter on the top left; however, it constantly displays a black screen with nothing in it. When I run my code, it doesn't display any errors at all.

```
import pygame
import time
from scripts.UltraColor import*

pygame.init()

currentSec = 0
currentFrame = 0
FramePerSec = 0

fps_font = pygame.font.Font("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf", 20)



def count_FramePerSecond():
    global currentSec, currentFrame, FramePerSec
    # during the current second, this will record how many frames there are
    if currentSec = time.strf("%S"):
        currentFrame += 1

    else:
        FramePerSec = currentFrame
        #records the frame that were added during the second

        currentFrame = 0
        #resets the counter back to zero so it can record during the next second
        currentSec = time.strf("%S"):
        #sets the current second variable to the current second

def show_FramesPerSecond():
    fps_overlay = fps_font.render(str(FramesPerSecond), True, Color.Goldenrod)
    window.blit(fps_overlay, (0,0))

def create_window():
    global window, window_title window_height, window_width, 

    window_title = "Crappy RPG Game"

    window_height = 700
    window_width = 900

    pygame.display.set_caption(window_title)

    window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_height, window_width), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)




create_window():

is_gameRunning = True

while is_gameRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_gameRunning = False


    #Logic
    count_FramePerSecond()

    #Render Graphics:
    window.fill(255,0,255)
    show_FramesPerSecond()

    pygame.display.update()




pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Again I am very new to both stack overflow and pygame so sorry if it is an obvious mistake

Comment: Your code isn't even running, its full of errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple syntax errors. Please install an IDE that will show them to you if you can't see the error messages (I'm not familiar with Windows sorry).

```
if currentSec = time.strf("%S"):
```

Should be:

```
if currentSec == time.strf("%S"):
```

Also:

```
    currentSec = time.strf("%S"):
```

=>

```
    currentSec = time.strf("%S")
```

Missing comma in `global window, window_title window_height, window_width,` and extra `:` here: `create_window():`

If you are a beginner, you should start with running examples, then adapt them to understand how that works. Do not try to write dozens of lines without even testing...

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH! I was not using an IDE for this one, that is why I couldn't see the error messages and assumed the code was working properly.